# How to parse a list of SearchResults?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using the App Engine search API and I'm trying to extract a list of doc_ids. Here is the result of my query:

```
search.SearchResults(results=[
    search.ScoredDocument(doc_id=u'-8853541246119947279', rank=0), 
    search.ScoredDocument(doc_id=u'-8853541246119948097', rank=0), 
    search.ScoredDocument(doc_id=u'-8853541246119946461', rank=0),      
    search.ScoredDocument(doc_id=u'51713103325273223', rank=0), 
    search.ScoredDocument(doc_id=u'5587798675278816831', rank=0), 
    search.ScoredDocument(doc_id=u'-8853541246119946464', rank=0), 
    search.ScoredDocument(doc_id=u'-3372400065395745350', rank=0), 
    search.ScoredDocument(doc_id=u'5587798675278815364', rank=0)
], number_found=8L)
```

How do I extract the `doc_id`s as a list?

Comment: its kind of a quirk but split the line on "'" and they fall out on every other line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read through the documents more:

```
results = index.search(search.Query(
            #query and options here, including ids_only=True
            ))
doc_ids = [tmp_result.doc_id for tmp_result in results]
```